# How to show Polars Dataframe in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide, python-polars

In PyCharm you have the ability to show a Pandas Dataframe with the SciView tool. Is this also possible with Polars or would I have to spam `print` statements?

(I also opened a PyCharm support ticket)

Comment: That needs to be supported my jetbrains I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polars DataFrames are not yet fully supported in PyCharm.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-2111 (was https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-50861 previously) -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the [jetbrains issue above](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-2111) with a workaround

using [polars api extensions](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api.html). by adding and importing the class below you can access the pandas equiv view from variable explorer provided you have pyarrow installed to run df.to_pandas()

```
@pl.api.register_dataframe_namespace("pd") 
class PolarsPd:
    def __init__(self, df: DF):
        self.df = df.to_pandas()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dfpl = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]})
```

[image]